# Can't send all data from one table to another using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, orm

the issue an invoice button is to send one row from the porform table to invoices. Most of the columns have the same names. And there is a problem because half of the value is not transferred. I call $proform over dd($proform) and it's all there. What am I doing wrong? Here you can see how I check the grossunit, and the values ​​are shown nicely, but it is not sent to the second table. This is part of my controller.

```
public function duplicate(Request $request)

{

$proform = $this->proform->findOrFail($request->duplicate);

$invoice = Invoice::all();

dd($proform->grossunit);

//something like this

$duplicated = Invoice::create([

'invoicenumber' => $proform->proformnumber,

'invoicedate' => $proform->proformdate,

'selldate' => $proform->selldate,

'user_id' => $proform->user_id,

'form_id' => $proform->form_id,

'currency_id' => $proform->currency_id,

'paymentmethod' => $proform->paymentmethod,

'paymentdate' => $proform->paymentdate,

'status' => $proform->status,

'comments' => $proform->comments,

'city' => $proform->city,

'autonumber' => $proform->autonumber,

'automonth' => $proform->automonth,

'autoyear' => $proform->autoyear,

'name' => $proform->name,

'PKWIU' => $proform->PKWIU,

'quantity' => $proform->quantity,

'unit' => $proform->unit,

'netunit' => $proform->netunit,

'nettotal' => $proform->nettotal,

'VATrate' => $proform->VATrate,

'grossunit' => $proform->grossunit,

'grosstotal' => $proform->grosstotal,

]);

return redirect()->route('invoices.show', ['invoice' => $duplicated]);

}
```

This is invoice model:

```
<?php


namespace App;

use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Invoice extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *  
     * @var array
     */
    use Sortable;
    
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'invoicenumber', 'invoicedate', 'id', 'selldate', 'user_id', 'paymentmethod', 
        'paymentdate', 'status', 'comments', 'city', 'paid',  'autonumber', 'automonth', 'autoyear', 'name',
         'PKWIU', 'quantity', 'unit', 'netunit', 'nettotal',
         'VATrate', 'grossunit', 'grosstotal', 'form_id', 'currency_id',
    ];
    
    public $sortable = [     'invoicenumber', 'invoicedate', 'id', 'selldate', 
    'user_id', 'paymentmethod', 'paymentdate', 'status', 'comments', 'grosstotal', 'nettotal', 'form_id', 'currency_id',];
    
        public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

        public function form()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Form');
    }

         public function currency()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Currency');
    }
   
        public function proform()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Proform');
    } 
    
}
```

This fields are not making it:
name, PKWIU , quantity, unit , netunit, nettotal, VATrate, grossunit, grosstotal

Comment: are all those fields 'fillable' on that Invoice model?

Comment: Yes. There are.

Comment: can you go into what fields are not "making" it or what the issue is in a lil more detail

Comment: this fields are not making it: 
name, PKWIU , quantity, unit , netunit, nettotal, VATrate, grossunit, grosstotal